# mysql - how to get all relationship foreign key missing from parent table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working for old project that are not include relationship foreign key. some category are missing.I want to get all products where category_id don't  exist in category_tbl

in the following table there is category_id 3 that don't exist in category_tbl

```
   category_tbl
    id name
     1 fruit
     2 animal

  product_tbl
     id name   category_id
     1  apple   1
     2  cat     2
     3  coffee  3
     4  tea     3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with NOT EXISTS:

```
select p.* 
from product_tbl p
where not exists (
  select 1 from category_tbl
  where id = p.category_id 
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sy5JtcPQEfaHXZJan4fwRF/0).
Results:

```
| id  | name  | category_id |
| --- | ----- | ----------- |
| 3   | coffe | 3           |
| 4   | tea   | 3           |
```

Comment: how can i get opposite of this? category_id that are not in producs table @forpas thanks

Comment: With `select id from category_tbl where id not in (select category_id from product_tbl)`

Answer (score 1):

you could use left join and chek for where category_id is null

```
 select  c.name
 from product_tbl p 
 left  join category_tbl c  ON p.category_id = c.id 
 where category_id  is null
```